# Count total records in File and compare with trailer records

Tags: shell

The contents of the file are as below

```
101,abc,2017-03-15,Linux
222,xyz,2016-10-10,Unix
987,def,2017-01-03,Solaris
567,tek,2014-01-09,windows
Trailer|20170331|4
```

I need to compare actual record line which is 4, is equal to total records on trailer(4).

Comment: Did you make an attempt yourself to solve the problem?

Comment: How would you like to get the output as?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple of assumptions:

1. There will only ever be the records you want to count and a single trailer record.  That is, no other types of data records, no headers, no extra trailer or subtotal records.
2. On the trailer record, the record count will always be the third field and the delimiter will always be a pipe ("|").

You didn't specify what specific OS or shell you're using, so you might need to tweak some of the commands due to minor differences.

Anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
recchk()
{
  #Here's the file we're working with:
  myfile=testfile.txt

  #Let's figure out how many records are in it
  recs=`wc -l $myfile | cut -f1 -d" "`

  #Now subtract 1 because we don't want to count the trailer
  let recs=`expr $recs - 1`

  echo "There are $recs data records in the file."

  #Now we'll find the trailer record and get the third field 
  trcnt=`tail -1 $myfile | cut -f3 -d"|"`

  echo "Trailer says there are $trcnt records."

  #Now we'll check to make sure all is well.
  if [ $recs -ne $trcnt ]; then
     echo "Uh-oh!  They don't match\!"
  else
     echo "Right on, daddy-o\!  We're righteous\!"
  fi
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Roger, Works perfectly fine, Just need one more information on the above, How can i pass filename as parameter in the function recchk(), so that this can be used across multiple scripts.

Comment: If you put the recchk() function in a separate file, such as recchk.sh, you can then import it in another script with `source <path>/recchk.sh`.  Then you can use the rechchk() function as if it were in your other script.

Comment: Suppose i have 5 text files and for each file, i have to check the total number of records and compare with trailer record and see if it matches. obviously 5 files will have different names and i want to reuse them by passing the file name in the function recchk(), how can i call the file name

Comment: You can use a "for" loop to loop through either a specific list of files or through all files in a directory, calling the recchk() function with each one.  Something this: `for f in "file1" "file2" "file3"; do recchk $f; done` or `for f in file*; do recchk $f; done`  That should get you pointed in the right direction.